# Echo get_option displays as text

Tags: php, functions, options, text

I am trying to use some code that is stored as a settings option in WordPress. When I try to use the following code below however, it show up as plain text instead of executing. The option I have created contains the following PHP code:

```
echo get_option('profiles_templates_html'. $template .'');
```

Comment: You are trying to _execute_ the PHP?

Comment: Storing PHP code in the DB is so, **SO** wrong. Whatever you're trying to do, don't do it that way. Please.

Comment: then how should I do it. I am trying to have a few different templates that I can use.

Comment: Have you wrapped it in `<?php ... ?>`?

Comment: as in in the option.. then yes.  please help.

Comment: I agree with the comments above. Don't try to execute raw PHP from the database. If you want help, rewrite the question to explain what you want to accomplish rather than ask about how to implement what is probably a poorly concieved solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want to execute code stored in a database, a quick google search reveals that you can use the eval() function to do just that. However, many people do say that [Eval is Evil](http://www.blog.highub.com/php-core/php-eval-is-evil/)...

Instead of storing the entire PHP code of an option in the database, try storing a simple boolean flag for your option and then test whether to get your template's option data from there:

```
<?php

// Somewhere else in your code, store the settings option upon saving settings
update_option( 'my_setting_for_template', 1 );

// Test if get_option returns 1 from the database
if( get_option( 'my_setting_for_template' ) === 1 )
{
    echo get_option('profiles_templates_html'. $template .'');
}

?>
```

References:

- [PHP Manual - eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
- [How Do I Execute Code Stored in a MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406/how-do-i-execute-php-that-is-stored-in-a-mysql-database)
- [When is PHP eval() Evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)